# Unable to select "a tag" with "img tag" inside to run AJAX function

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, anchor, selector

I am running an ajax function that calls an external page but am having trouble selecting an anchor tag that has an image inside of it. The function works when it is plain text but once there is an image inside it ceases to function (except when clicked outside of the image but within the anchor tag).

The html is something like this.

```
    <div id="add_content">
        <a href="page_1.html"> Text works fine</a>
        <a href="page_2.html"><img src="thumbnail.jpg"/>Image doesn't work</a>
    </div>

    <div id="insert_here"> </div>
```

An example external page is

```
    <div id="thumbnails">
        <img src="images/1.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/2.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/3.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

The script that I am running is

```
       $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#add_content a').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#insert_here').load(e.target.href + '#thumbnails').hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
            });
       });
```

Comment: So what actually doesn't work? Please don't respond with "function doesn't work"

Comment: start by using proper markup on the img tag....  <img src />

Comment: @John B: "proper" from which perspective?

Comment: What doesn't work is the image inside of an anchor. While hovering the cursor appears but when clicking it doesn't call the external page. In the case that the image doesn't completely fill the anchor tag, the portion that isn't an image is clickable and leads to the external page.

Comment: @zerkms Markup wise.  Maybe I'm just being ocd since its not that big a deal, but I like to close all my img tags in case some stupid client of mine tries to view a heavily scripted page with some shitty old browser and then tries to blame me when things break.

Comment: @JohnB - Self-closing tags on void elements like `img` aren't required unless using xhtml. They're optional in html5, and (arguably, depending on doctype) wrong under html4. Old browsers don't need 'em.

Comment: @nnnnnn good to know.  I'd been working under the assumption that it was proper makeup.  thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `e.target.href` to `this.href`:

```
$('#insert_here').load(this.href + '#thumbnails').hide().delay(100).fadeIn(500);
```

If you click on the child image then `e.target` will be that image, and the image doesn't have an `href` property. The click event is bound to the anchors, so within the click handler `this` will be the anchor that was clicked.

The reason your current code worked "when clicked outside of the image but within the anchor tag" is because in that case `e.target` is the anchor itself.

Answer (score 0):

Put a space before the id selector so that the line reads:

```
$('#insert_here').load(e.target.href + ' #thumbnails')
```